# Make dynamic width of elements inside of flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Well, I'm not good with the flex, because I don't use it a lot, but I think there is no other way how to make this happen. I want to make simple form, which will have label with description and input on its right side. This description can have any size and input would increase its size to fulfill the parent. Here is the code:

```css
div {
    display: flex;
    width: 300px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
label {
    height: 21px;
    line-height: 21px;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: black;
    flex: 1;
}
input {
    margin-left: 20px;
    flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <label>Company</label>
    <input type="text">
</div>
<div>
    <label>Street</label>
    <input type="text">
</div>
<div>
    <label>Who are you?</label>
    <input type="text">
</div>
```

It should looks like this:

[image]

Comment: may be bootstrap input-group-addon can also help you. check it once https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/input-group/

Comment: It would be more work to get rid of all these styles (backgrounds, padding, borders...). Anyway, I use foundation, so there would be conflict.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You just have to set the flex property of `label` to: `flex: 0 1 auto`. This means: `flex-grow: 0`, `flex-shrink: 1` `flex-basis: auto`

```css
div {
    display: flex;
    width: 300px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
label {
    height: 21px;
    line-height: 21px;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: black;
    flex: 0 1 auto;
}
input {
    margin-left: 20px;
    flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <label>Company</label>
    <input type="text">
</div>
<div>
    <label>Street</label>
    <input type="text">
</div>
<div>
    <label>Who are you?</label>
    <input type="text">
</div>
```

Comment: This fails if you change the div width from `300px` to `200px`.  To fix, also set the input's `min-width: 0`

Answer (score 3):

Just add flex-order to label and input tags
See here http://codepen.io/tantata/pen/KNoMWQ

```css
div {
    display: flex;
    width: 300px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    flex-wrap:nowrap;
}
label {
    height: 21px;
    line-height: 21px;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: black;
    flex-grow: 0;
}
input {
    margin-left: 20px;
    flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <label>Company</label>
    <input type="text">
</div>
<div>
    <label>Street</label>
    <input type="text">
</div>
<div>
    <label>Who are you?</label>
    <input type="text">
</div>
```